# SQL - Table Relationships, Primarily (PK/FK)

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, primary-key, table-relationships

I am new to SQL and I have a question regarding table relationships.  Currently, I have the following tables in my database:

**Person:**

```
Person_ID (PK)
Name
Company_ID(FK)
Phone
Email
```

**Company:**

```
Company_ID (PK)
Name
Address
City
State
Invoice_ID (FK)
```

**Invoice:**

```
Invoice_ID (PK)
Summary_ID (FK)
Detailed_ID (FK)
```

**Summary_Section:**

```
Summary_ID (PK)
InvoiceNumber
Date
DueDate
```

**Detailed_Section:**

```
Detailed_ID (PK)
Person_ID (FK)
Amount
Info
```

Basically, each company has multiple people and receives one invoice.

Each invoice is broken into two sections:

- Summary
- Detailed

The *summary* section shows the company name, company address, invoice number, invoice date, & due date.

The *detailed* section shows the person's name, amount, & additional info.

Am I going about this all wrong? What would be the best way to go about this?  Thank you!

**EDIT:**

Concern: Am I assigning the foreign/primary keys correctly in this scenario?

Comment: What specific concerns do you have?

Comment: The relationships look fine to me, assuming that all the foreign keys are linking back to the primary keys of the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PK/FK assignment seems to be ok. Although I would suggest the following:

1. If you are using any kind of framework, try to be consistent with its conventions. For example, Ruby on Rails usually calls the primary key (if it is just one column) as id for all tables. Note: column names across tables don't have to be unique.
2. Do you really need to separate the summary and detailed sections in the DB? You could combine the Invoice, Summary, and Detailed in one table, and then just retrieve/display the columns you need. This is both a design and engineering issue.

   - Design: Can two invoices ever share a section?
   - Engineering: How many times do you think the sections might be edited/retrieved?

Comment: Good point, I'll combine the invoice tables and make those changes to the PKs.  Thank you!